# Showing google map marker in specified circle/area only

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps

I want to show the markers in the specified area only! For example, I want to draw the circle with radius suppose 3 or any and center (any LatLng). Then, I need to display the marker only in the regions of that circle.
How can I achieve that? Is it possible?

Update: Solution to my question

```
function isMarkerInArea(circle, marker)
{
   return (circle.getBounds().contains(marker.getPosition()));
};
```

Description:

- circle.getBounds() returns the latLng bounds of circle
- marker.getPosition() returns the latLng of the marker
- and finally circle.getBounds().contains(marker.getPosition()) , returns the boolean value if the marker is within the circle all not.

Finally, set the visibility of the marker as per the boolean returned!

Comment: Do you have lat and long of the markers? Please explain further.

Comment: yeah I have got latlng for markers in mmy database!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach (assuming your have an array of markers) would be to use circle's `contains()` function. 
An example:

```
function isMarkerInArea(circle, marker){
   return (circle.getBounds().contains(marker.getPosition());
};
```

This function will return a `boolean`. If it is true you set display the marker, otherwise you hide it.

Comment: Thanks @Uros, it works for me! But there is ) missing in return before ;

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know exactly what you are doing but I'm going to assume you have an array of markers and you want to only display the ones within a certain circle you define.  You can use the square of the differences to calculate a fairly decent distance (if it's small).  Say you have a known center point of your circle Cx and Cy and an array P.  Compare this formula for array item i: (P[i]x-Cx)*(P[i]x-Cx) + (P[i]y-Cy)*(P[i]y-Cy) to the square of the distance you care about (say 3000 meters or whatever).  Don't bother with a square root as this is processing intensive.  Just work with the squares.  Then only draw the markers that are under your limit.

Do I understand your problem correctly?  Perhaps you are doing something different than what I immagine.

Comment: I am actually confused with your answer. My problem is I have got latlng of vehicle in my database and when user enter his/her co-ordinates. I want to show only those vehicles located near his/her location (say around 300-400 meters radius) using markers. I hope now you get my problem clearly. So, if you could help me with the solution. :)

Comment: OK, so I didn't explain units in my answer... If you want to use 300 meters as your limit then your comparison number will be 300 * 300 = 90,000. To get the lat/lon numbers (in degrees) to be in meters you have to convert using sections of the radius of the earth.  Assuming the earth radius is E=6371009 meters (for northern hemisphere) you multiply each value by E * PI / 180.  This does not take into account he curvature of the earth so it is approximately correct for small distances like 300 meters.  Let me know if that is not clear enough.